# Days you shouldn't visit a cemetery

Tags: halacha, mysticism-kabbalah, cemetery-grave

Someone told me you shouldn't visit a cemetery on Friday.
Is this correct?

More generally, are there any other days (holidays, events, etc) that you shouldn't go to a cemetery?

Comment: [Hilchot Avel 4:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e404.htm#4)

Comment: The Vilna Gaon held one should refrain from going,ותשמר שלא תלך לבית הקברות כלל וכלל. (נ"א: ששם מתדבקין הקלפות מאד וכל שכן בנשים), וכל הצרות והעונות באים מזה. וגם

Comment: @sam where is the Vilna Gaon

Comment: In his iggeres hagra

Comment: I have heard the Ari also said one should not visit a cemetery other than for burying/escorting the deceased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Shulchan Aruch there is no mention of days that one cannot visit a cemetery.

There are Halachot that apply when visiting a cemetery on various days.

For example, when entering a cemetery - after not being there for 30 days - one says a Bracha. See [here](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9F) or [here](http://www.jewish-funeral-guide.com/tradition/blessing-jewish-cemetery.htm) for Nusach.

One then continues with Tziduk Hadin - which is not said on days when *Tachanun* is not said - including **Erev Shabbat** and Erev Yom Tov. (Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 188:14)

This may be the source of the *rumour* that you heard.

Since one must be happy on Yom Tov and may not be sad on Shabbat, one probably should not be visiting cemeteries on those days.

That said, (as mentioned in the comments) the Rambam, Vilna Gaon and other frown upon visiting a cemetery, if not for burials.